# Css child selector on .row not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am totally not sure it has to do with my selector. I am using bootstrap and I am trying to make the three buttons of .row be on same line even after width< 576px. I tried changing the flex-wrap property to nowrap. But it is not working.
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="button-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xm-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary active" id="all">All</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xm-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="online">Online</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xm-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="offline">Offline</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .container{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .btn{
        width: 100px;
    }
    #button-container>row{
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3 or 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`col-xs-4`** instead of **`col-xm-4`**.

No need to write media query

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div id="button-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary active" id="all">All</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="online">Online</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="offline">Offline</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And as a alternate if you are not able to change HTML part use below media query *(you have not used `.` before `row` in your media queries)*

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  #button-container>.row {
    display: flex;
  }
  #button-container>.row>div {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but can you also tell me the way for media query. In future it might help

Comment: @SamratLuitel It should work, you can check it in above snippet. BTW for an alternate I have also given media query code. See updated answer.

Comment: We don't answer questions with typo, we vote/flag to close as _"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."_

Comment: @LGSon yes the OP made a typo error but the whole question was not about typo error. OP also asked that why his media query not working?

Comment: A missing dot `.` is also a typo, especially as it is only missing at one place, and were used in the title.

Comment: @LGSon OP did not apply the `display: flex` property to the `row` and using `flex-wrap: nowrap` which was wrong. Also OP have to set `flex:1` to the child div to achieve the desired result

Comment: With the typo fixed, OP's code already work, using Bootstrap 3, w/o the media query, using Bootstrap 4 with `flex-wrap: nowrap;` in the query. And changing the answer to _I think your code should work..._ is even worse than when comment on the typo's

Comment: @LGSon Yes, but after the typo fixed OP said its not working.